# How do arrange arrays with different combinations?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have 3 arrays `["s","m"]`, `["Red","Black"]`, `["1", "2"]`. I want to arrange them like this:

```
["s","Red","1"],
["s","Red","2"], 
["s","Black","1"], 
["s","Black","2"],

["m","Red","1"],
["m","Red","2"], 
["m","Black","1"], 
["m","Black","2"],
```

I'm out of idea, please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop each one then just combine them into an array.

#### Script:

```
function test() {
  arr1 = ["s","m"]
  arr2 = ["Red","Black"]
  arr3 = ["1", "2"]

  arr1.forEach(x => {
    arr2.forEach(y => {
      arr3.forEach(z => {
        console.log([x, y, z]);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

```
  let a = ["s","m"]
  let b = ["Red","Black"]
  let c = ["1", "2"]


for(let i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++){
    for(let j = 0 ; j < b.length ; j++){
        for(let k = 0 ; k < c.length ; k++){
            console.log(a[i], b[j], c[k])
           
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make 3 nested loops, some thing like:

```
for (int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
       
       for(int j = 0; j<2; j++) {
           
           for(int k = 0; k<2; k++) {
               
               //put your code here
           }
       }
   }
```